# Access and managing of few Twilio chat instances from any component of the react/react-native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Is there any way to have access to a few Twilio chat instances from any component of the application? Or have access to them in the parent component at least? I've tried to use a Redux as a store for chat instances, channels, etc. but my redux dev tools had a memory leaking problem. I think the problem was in a complicated Twilio object's structure and his circular references. Anyway storing non-serializable structures in the Redux is a bad practice at all. In my project, I'm using react-navigation v5. Could it help me to deal with the problem?